# Reduce abnormally high bundle size

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle

My bundle size for a small single-page React project is abnormally high (19mb in development mode), (7mb in production mode).

I have tried to search for potential solutions, but most solutions deal with optimizing at the sub-megabyte level. However, this is a pathological case and I am certain that I must have a gross configuration mistake causing the abnormal size. The distribution is as follows:

[image]

In actuality, webpack output says the bundle size is 27Mb (!):

```
Version: webpack 4.44.1
Time: 29086ms
Built at: 11/17/2020 5:52:02 PM
                                                      Asset      Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
                                                favicon.ico  1.26 KiB          [emitted]              
                                                 index.html  2.02 KiB          [emitted]              
                                             main.bundle.js  27.4 MiB    main  [emitted]              main
Entrypoint main = main.bundle.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0 ./client/index.tsx 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./client/app.tsx] 1.19 KiB {main} [built]
[./client/css/index.css] 525 bytes {main} [built]
[./client/index.css] 519 bytes {main} [built]
[./client/index.tsx] 299 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.less] 539 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 8.65 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js] 127 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0 8.26 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.59 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
    + 4603 hidden modules
Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
     1 asset
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html] 2.26 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Things I have tried / facts:

- using webpack 4.44.1
- ensure no unused imports
- try to import as low in the hierarchy as possible (`import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core"` instead of `import Amplify from` "aws-amplify"`)
- split into chunks
- various compressions

Here is my configuration:

- `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "sideEffects": [
    "*.css"
  ],
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.dev.js --history-api-fallback --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.1.0",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.1.3",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
    "@types/react-responsive": "^8.0.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/stripe": "^7.13.25",
    "antd": "^4.2.4",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.0.12",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "lodash": "4.17.13",
    "rc-queue-anim": "^1.8.5",
    "rc-scroll-anim": "^2.7.5",
    "rc-tween-one": "^2.7.3",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-responsive": "^8.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "**/@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "**/upath": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

- `webpack.common.js`:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const utils = require("./build-utils");

const path = require("path");

const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require("lodash-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer")
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".ts", ".graphql"],
    modules: ["./client, "node_modules"],
  },
  entry: "./client/index.tsx",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contentHash].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    chunkFilename: "[chunkhash].js",
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),
    new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts(x)?$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "ts-loader", options: { onlyCompileBundledFiles: true } },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.graphql?$/,
        use: [{ loader: "webpack-graphql-loader" }],
      },     
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
          },
          {
            loader: "less-loader", // compiles Less to CSS
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                modifyVars: {
                  "border-radius-base": "2px",
                },
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif|ico)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "images/[hash]-[name].[ext]",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ico$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
          },
        ],
      },

    ],
  },
};
```

- `webpack.config.dev.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const common = require("./webpack.common");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");

const path = require("path");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist_dev"),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),
  ],
});
```

Are there any pointers towards reducing the size to a reasonable number?

Comment: Are you optimizing for production or development? Production seems fine to me as you are including all the libraries in one bundle. You can potentially split vendor bundle and keep your files in main bundle.

Comment: @Rikin both. The production config produces a main bundle and then a vendor bundle that is 7mb large, yielding poor performance.

Comment: Were you able to find out any solution?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar unfortunately I did not. I only implemented workarounds such as splitting into multiple chunks to fetch in parallel. The total size is still absurdly high.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar were you? I'm trying to solve this again; but to no avail.